# Tips for Properly Installing a PVC Gable Vent in an Older Home

Tags: vent, gable

I'm planning to replace an old metal gable vent with a new 15x15 inch PVC louver vent on my house, built in the 60s. I aim to ensure a seamless and secure installation and would appreciate advice on the following points:

- Sealing and Fitting: What are the best practices for ensuring a proper seal and fit between the new PVC vent and the existing structure?
- Tools and Materials: Are there specific tools or materials recommended for installing PVC vents that might differ from those used for metal vents?
- Old Home Considerations: Given the age of my home, are there any particular challenges I should be prepared for when replacing the vent?

I have two options for the PVC vents; one is a single piece that's quite flexible, and the other is sturdier but in two pieces, potentially requiring modification to fit around roof struts.

Here are the photos of the current setup and the two vents: https://imgur.com/a/E33FTaG

The second vent was purchased here: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Royal-21000-15-in-x-15-in-White-Square-PVC-Gable-Vent/3369732

I'm specifically looking for guidance on installing the PVC gable vent correctly to avoid any potential issues. Thank you!

Comment: Personally, I'd prime and paint beneath the edge to seal the exposed wood, set the vent in place, and run a bead of polyurethane (e.g. OSI Quad Max) caulk around the edge.  Without holding both of your vents in my hand, I'm not sure which to use.  Given this is not a high load application, I'm not sure I really care how flimsy it might be.

Comment: The second vent is from lowes home improvement: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Royal-21000-15-in-x-15-in-White-Square-PVC-Gable-Vent/3369732

Its a nicer, stiffer vent. The other is very flimsy like slightly better than cheap plastic bottle flimsy. The only difference is the flimsy one seems simpler to install, whereas the Lowe's one comes in two pieces and I am assuming one side goes inside the attic.